# struts2: blank page on OGNL error etc

Tags: struts2

In case of problems on page I just get a blank page, no stacktraces in console etc.
Is there a way to fix this, or improve the diagnostics?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting [devmode=true](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/devmode.html) ?
Can you give us more details (struts2 version, jsp fragment, using sitemesh/tiles or not)?

Comment: Yeah, I have the line  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/> in my config.

Struts version is 2.1.8.1, no sitemesh/tiles.

I happens for example every time the property I bind the tag to is missing(missspelt): <s:select name="offerersSelector.selectedIds" ... />

Comment: This kind of exceptions should appear in your logs. Is you struts2 logging somewhere ? (you mentioned only "no stacktraces in console")